# OPC UA Unique NodeId

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I have a question concerning the OPC Foundation's Unified Architecture. For the ObjectType NodeClass, Object NodeClass, VariableType NodeClass, Variable NodeClass, and DataType NodeClass, each of them have at least 1 property. Each property is represented by a Variable Node.

Say I instantiate a Variable Node from its NodeClass followed by its NodeVersion property that is represented by a Variable Node and related to the Variable Node via a HasProperty reference. Is the Node ID of the NodeVersion property unique within the context of the server OR is the numeric identifier a constant value of 3068 (taken from https://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/1.02/NodeIds.csv)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NodeId must be unique within the context of the server.

Don't confuse your own instantiated nodes with the Nodes and NodeIds that are modeled as part of the default address space (defined in both the specification and the schema files at https://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/).